# How can I create a content widget generator?

Tags: rss, syndication

Sites like Buzzfeed offer widgets (Javascript, PHP, WordPress, etc.) for syndicating their content on other sites. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could go about creating/implementing some kind of interactive widget generator that gives users options for customizing their widget? I assume this would require RSS.

Check out the Buzzfeed generator to see what I mean
http://www.buzzfeed.com/network/widget

Answer (score 0):

Buzzfeed is using an iframe for a widget which isn't too complicated to make. Widgets are mostly meant for ease of use and for people who aren't familiar with RSS feeds and how to work with them. For example you could embed images into your RSS feed and let visitors know, then they could customize it as they want on their own website.

To do what BuzzFeed does you'll need jQuery to change the CSS styles of the table containing the images and post titles. As the styles change update the code displayed to the visitors so they can copy it and paste it into their site.